# to upload the image equal =5 mb

Tags: image, image-uploading

**my first page**

```
<form action="2.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>



<?php
include "config.php";
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  $a=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
```

my 1st page is my form from which i select the file and click on the submit button 
I want to upload the image equal to 5 MB and not more than 5 mb  but I don't how to set limit the size of image  .

Comment: do you mean you want to limit it to 5mb?

Comment: where is the code with the form? The size is probably limited on the client side.

Comment: you want to do something like if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 5000000) obveously calculate the size of 5mb

Comment: @LiamSorsby I have done this bt its showing me the error

Comment: what error does it show?

Comment: **Error: 1**  this error is coming

Comment: @LiamSorsby and my file is 5 mb only

Comment: can you edit your file above and put the code you used to test it and then the exact error that was recieved. Also can you check your php.ini file to see what the maximum post size is?

Comment: @LiamSorsby I am using this same code only but i am not able to upload more than 2 mb

Comment: @LiamSorsby if the image is more than 2 mb , its showing me **echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your php.ini defaults to a maximum of 2mb upload you need to increase the size in your php.ini file. try changing the following lines to this:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

maybe don't set it to 40m maybe limit to 6 or 7 unless you plan on uploading more then this. unfortunately unless you have access to your php.ini file you are unable to change this specific value using ini_set.